# Weird duplication error in Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access

I have a form that has a "duplicate record" button, and a combo box that is used to browse through the records by their short title. Sometimes when I duplicate the record I get this weird error and have no idea why. Say the short title was "ABCDE". If I duplicate it, the new record will have something like "ABCDEȀп" in the combo box, and I have to delete the combo box entry before I can work with the new record. Also - the short title field in the actual form is fine; the weird characters are not entered into that, just into the combo box. I should also point out that the short title is not the primary key, so there is no issue with having duplicates of it. Does anyone know what could be causing this, or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

What formula/code are you using to generate the duplicate value? Is the combo box formatted as short text or long text/memo?

Comment: I just use the generic "duplicate record" button to create the duplicate one. I currently have it as short text.

Comment: Looking at the macro associated with the "duplicate record" buttons, I wouldn't do it the way MS has it set up. I would make a new button that does an append of the current short title to that table, then a macro to go to the last record. Don't know if that will help, but it will certainly simplify the macro. If it doesn't help, the next step will be to look at the combo box's properties and find the issue there, I think.